# F2FS is being displayed as an "Unknown" file system after formatting my pendrive. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, usb-drive, f2fs

I have tried formatting my Kingston 4GB pen drive to F2FS using "gparted" on ubuntu 14.04. After the format is completed, the tab under File System displays "Unknown" instead of "F2FS". Also, gparted doesn't show anything under used and unused spaces. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?